# Qual o nome do menu que exibe detalhes no Android?

Tags: android, apache-cordova

O menu que quando você clica em um título aparece as opções para você.

Comment: Desculpe @daniel12345smith mas não consegui entender sua pergunta corretamente, você está desenvolvendo para Android e gostaria de um botão que ao ser acionado expanda com opções disponíveis para você escolher? Você está desenvolvendo nativamente ou está usando o Phonegap?

Comment: quero fazer um app de lista de compras, onde em um formulário apareça a opção bebida e quando clicar nela, abrir novas opções, como se fosse um submenu ou um botão que "abre" vários outros. tem muitos destes menus nos apps Android, porém esqueci o nome e não estou conseguindo achar...

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione mais detalhes (esses do comentário já ajudam), está difícil de entender o que pretende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o Phonegap, então recomendo que use o JQuery Mobile, pois ele possui um recurso chamado **collapsible** e sua maneira de usar pode ser encontrada [aqui](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/collapsible/).

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Isso vai aparecer no botão</h4>
    <button>opção1</button>
<button>opção2</button>
</div>
```